# How to auto deploy/build SSAS and SSRS solution using TeamCity

Tags: reporting-services, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, ssas

We are working on some BI projects using MS SS*S, and we also have the asp.net Web UI as the container for our SSRS report which reading data from OLAP cubes
It's pretty straight forward to use TeamCity as CI tool for asp.net websites, and we are looking for similar approach for SS*S, we made some practice to use scripts to build and deploy SSAS but it require BIDS to be install to teamcity server, 
So does MSbuild support SS*S build and deployment?
is there any TeamCity embedded tool for SS*S build and deployment?
Any best practice for this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Teamcity buildagents are purposed to have required tools installed on it. If you need BIDS to build your project - install it on your teamcity buildagent. If you don't want to install it on your teamcity server - just move your agent to another server.

It's very popular practice when TeamCity server also acts as build agent for itself, but it's not mandatory and you can set up another server\VM as build agent with all tools you need for particular project build. This way you can set up various (you need this especially when different version of build tools can't be installed side by side) build environments for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i did it, with Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) installed on agent.

1. I create a xml file for msbuild, the first command is to build the project, this will create the asdatabase file. the second command is to deploy the cube.

[image]

2. I create a build step in teamcity, that point to the xml previously created
   [image]

[image]

Hope this help